# Count Duplicates by occurrence

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 columns.
In one of the columns i have the text "Multi-Drop" and blanks (col-2).

In the other one i have "First Line" and blanks (col-1)

I would like to count the duplicates from col-2 until First Line from col-1 occurs leaving out the blanks in col-3

This would need to be flexible as i won't be selecting a certain range, but the whole column.

I have already tried to play around with the below and offset as well, but i only could get so far as counting the whole column.

```
=IF(B2=A1,C1,C1+1)
```

This is a demo of my data, and the expected result (The space between the 1st line of text and the second are blanks)

As you can see First-Line occurs on the first instances of Multi-Drop,but that is based on another formula.

```
col-1            col-2          Expected Result  


First Line       Multi-Drop      2



                 Multi-Drop     2
First Line       Multi-Drop     5
                 Multi-Drop     5
                 Multi-Drop     5
                 Multi-Drop     5
                 Multi-Drop     5
First Line       Multi-Drop     4
                 Multi-Drop     4
                 Multi-Drop     4
                 Multi-Drop     4
First Line       Multi-Drop     2
                 Multi-Drop     2
```

Comment: i think you could use VBa

Comment: I would prefer functions over VBA, but anything will do for now. Any ideeas as where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that data is located at `A2:B17` enter this `FormulaArray` in `C2` the copy down till `C17`:

*Formulas Array are entered pressing* `[Ctrl]` *+* `[Shift]` *+* `[Enter]` *simultaneously, you shall see* `{` *and* `}` *around the formula if entered correctly*

```
= IF( EXACT( B2, "" ), "",
IF( EXACT( A2, "First Line" ),
COUNTIF( INDEX(B:B, ROW() )
:INDEX(B:B, IFERROR( - 1 + ROW() + MATCH( "First Line", A3:A$1048576, 0 ), 1048576 ) ), "Multi-Drop" ),
IF( NOT( EXACT( C1, "" ) ), C1,
INDEX(C:C, MAX( ( ( C1:C$2 <> "" ) * 1 ) * ROW( C1:C$2 ) ) ) ) ) )
```

[image]

Suggest to see the following pages for additional information about the functions used:
[Excel functions (alphabetical)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-functions-alphabetical-b3944572-255d-4efb-bb96-c6d90033e188)

[IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611)
[INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd)
[MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)
[ROW function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/row-function-3a63b74a-c4d0-4093-b49a-e76eb49a6d8d)

Comment: That's exactly what i needed. Amazing job! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't doing 100% of what you want, but you can take it from there.

For cell C2:

```
=IF(A2="First Line",C3,IF(A1="",C1,Match("First Line",A2:A500,0)))
```

That works fine if column B has no empty spots.

The last duplicates wont work as it checks the amount of cells between 2 occurances of "First Line". Since no 2nd "First Line" is coming, it gives you an error.

Is that enough help or can you take it from here? I would post a comment instead but I don't have enough points yet, so I can only post answers.

[This is a snippet of what I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPrao.png)

Edit:
Forgot that English Excel uses , instead of ;

Fixed that in my code.

Comment: Hi,thank you. Wonderfully done. I just need now a way to not include the blanks in the count.

Comment: Weird how it returns n/a on the last few rows. Hmm

Comment: That happens because of this:

Let's say "First Line" appears for the last time on A432. Then C432 copies what is in C433. C433 has its array from A433 to whereever value you put there. I had used +500 in my example. Since A433 and the following are empty, it doesn't find any results, thus the n/a.

Comment: You can try to catch that error with iferror or however that is called in English Excel. I tried something like this within my 2nd IF-clause around the match-function:

iferror(Match("First Line",A2:A500,0),countif(B1:B500,"Multi-Drop")).

That would mean if an error occurs, it goes up one row and starts counting how many times "Multi-Drop" appears afterwards.

Comment: Nicely explained. Working fine now , thanx

Comment: Still couldn't figure how not to count the blanks. Think you can assist me some more?